# How to use the GET method in order to fetch data that's saved in the POST method via Django DRF API call?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API that allows me to save an image using the POST method via APIView in Django Rest Framework. The image that's saved in the POST method should be displayed within the GET method in the API webpage. The image that's stored is not saved in a model but in a local directory.

I don't wish to grab the image name from the directory via the GET method since I will be saving image(s) in a remote server in the near future. However, I would like to make the process dynamic so that the GET method can capture/fetch the image name after a user uploads and submits an image using POSTMAN. How can this be done?

Currently, this is what I had done so far:

```
class API(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    #Need to display the image name here that was saved using the POST method below.
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        image_filename = self.request.GET.get('image')
        return Response({'image_name' : image_filename}, status=200)

    def post(self, request):
        #key is 'image', value is the file uploaded in the system
        data = self.request.data    #image that gets uploaded
        img_file = data['image']
        if img_file:
            uploaded_file = img_file
            image = [{"image_name": uploaded_file}]  
            return Response(image, status = 200)                
        else:
            return Response("Please upload an image", status = 400)
```

The POST method works fine but when refreshing the API url, I am getting this result:

```
None
```

I was expecting a result like this:

```
{"image_name" : <"image_filename_that's_saved_in_the_POST_method">}
```

Can anyone explain what went wrong and what are the right steps which I should take in order to implement this requirement?

Comment: use can use serializer. then will not need get(). you can get uploaded image in response.

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example for me, Sandeep? I am fairly new to DRF.

Comment: can you show model.

Comment: I don't have a model. I mentioned it in my question above. The image will not be stored since I won't be needing it. I just want to grab the image name saved in POST method and view it in my browser API using GET. Or rather, is there any other way to perform this action?

Comment: @sandeep any luck?

Comment: I think you are getting None because you are not saving image. I just tried my way to get what you want and I get this "{"img": null}". I think you should consider saving image. You can delete it after use.

Comment: Hmm is it possible to use serializers in order to save the image data in the POST method and then view the image name in the GET method by using the same serializer?

Comment: Yes. you can use get() and post() with same serializer.

Comment: This can be done without a model, right? If so, can you please demonstrate an example or provide a good source? I cannot find a solution for the past 3 hours and it's driving me insane ... :(

Comment: No. this will need model. Why are you not using models?

Comment: I just want to call the API url everytime a client uploads an image. Once uploaded, the image name should be displayed in the DRF API browser. That's all actually. I don't wish to use a model for this purpose, just call the API and display the image name.